# json make separated into double quotes

Tags: php

I have a string like this from my data.

```
Categories { "0: Snack, 1:Juice, 2:Any "}
```

I want to output it this way instead,

```
{"0: Snack", "1:Juice", "2:Any"}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: i don't see any json or any php - would you please share the code with which you have trouble?

Comment: That is not a JSON String, what does it really look like

Comment: What you say you want is not a JSON data structure.

Comment: Please explain what you really want us to code for you, otherwise you are only going to get guesses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your non-JSON string:

```
$your_string = '{ "0: Snack, 1:Juice, 2:Any "}';
```

Trim off the outer brackets, quotes, and space, then explode on comma:

```
$trimmed = trim($your_string, '{}" ');
$split = explode(', ', $trimmed);
```

This will get you an array like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '0: Snack' (length=8)
  1 => string '1:Juice' (length=7)
  2 => string '2:Any' (length=5)
```

From that point, you can get the non-JSON result you want like this:

```
$result = '{"' . implode('", "', $split ) . '"}';
```

Or actually get JSON like this:

```
$resplit = array_map(function($x) { return explode(':', $x); }, $split);
$indexed = array_column($resplit, 1, 0);
$json = json_encode($indexed);
```

Note that since you have integer indexes that are zero-based and sequential, the JSON you end up with will be an array (`[" Snack","Juice","Any"]`) rather than an object (`{"0":" Snack","1":"Juice","2":"Any"}`). For any other indexes, you would get the object form.